# How to find multiple class in one li in ul using jquery

Tags: jquery

I searched much but could not find one thing that is :-
How to find multiple class combination in one li in ul using jquery.

My Example looks like :-

```
<ul id="ssl">
<li class="lll-84 home ADSL2">Test1</li>
<li class="lll-84 home ADSL2">Test1</li>
<li class="lll-85 home ADSL1">Test1</li>
<li class="lll-85 home ADSL1">Test1</li>
<li class="lll-86 home ADSL1">Test1</li>
</ul>
```

I want to hide all lis which are not having class =  lll-84 home ADSL2
the whole combination :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-class selector ( or [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method ) to filter out `li` which doesn't have certain class combination. For hiding the elements you can use [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) method in jQuery.

```js
$('#ssl li:not(.lll-84.home.ADSL2)').hide()
// or
$('#ssl li').not('.lll-84.home.ADSL2').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ssl">
  <li class="lll-84 home ADSL2">Test1</li>
  <li class="lll-84 home ADSL2">Test1</li>
  <li class="lll-85 home ADSL1">Test1</li>
  <li class="lll-85 home ADSL1">Test1</li>
  <li class="lll-86 home ADSL1">Test1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you pranav for your answer :)
Yes it's working fine now :)
Thanks again :)

Comment: @KA9 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('li').not('.lll-84.home.ADSL2').addClass('hide')
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ssl">
  <li class="lll-84 home ADSL2">Test1</li>
  <li class="lll-84 home ADSL2">Test2</li>
  <li class="lll-85 home ADSL1">Test3</li>
  <li class="lll-85 home ADSL1">Test4</li>
  <li class="lll-86 home ADSL1">Test5</li>
</ul>
I want to hide all lis which are not having class = lll-84 home ADSL2 the whole combination :)
```

Use method [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

> Description: Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

Comment: Thank you Guradio for your answer :)
Working fine now :)
I took not from your and above one's answer :)
Thanks again :)